# Excel VBA copy-paste only the visible filtered values from one column to another

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy-paste **only** the visible filtered (date) values from column "B" to column "Y". (In filtered condition I can only copy small portions of column "B" to "Y".)

[image]

I tried to do this with a the help of the below macro. This doesn't work unfortunately because it copies everything (also non filtered values) from column "B" to "Y" and I want to keep the non filtered data in "Y"

```
x = 4
Do While Cells(x, 1).Value <> ""
Cells(x, 25).Value = Cells(x, 2).Value
x = x + 1
Loop
```

I also tried variants like here below, but these copy also just a portion of column B or the code throws errors.

```
Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row, 2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
ActiveSheet.Range (Cells(4, 25).PasteSpecial(xlPasteAll)) ' Range("Y4").PasteSpecial(xlPasteAll))
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Could you share the complete code so we can build on it?

Comment: hi VBasic2008, these are the subs I'm working with, it's only for copying the cells from one column to another

Answer (score 2):

### Copy Filtered Data to Another Column

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyToY()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' be more specific
    
    ' First Cell of the Data Range (in the row below headers)
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range("B4")
    ' Last Cell of the Filtered Range
    Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    ' If no filtered data, the last cell will be the header cell, which
    ' is above the first cell. Check this with:
    If lCell.Row < fCell.Row Then Exit Sub ' no filtered data
    
    ' Range from First Cell to Last Cell
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(fCell, lCell)
    
    ' Filtered Data Range
    Dim frg As Range: Set frg = rg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    ' Area Range
    Dim arg As Range
    
    For Each arg In frg.Areas
        ' Either copy values (more efficient (faster))...
        arg.EntireRow.Columns("Y").Value = arg.Value
        ' ... or copy values, formulas and formatting
        'arg.Copy arg.EntireRow.Columns("Y")
    Next arg
    
    MsgBox "Filtered data copied to column ""Y"".", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: wow, this works very efficient, thnx :)